# Test for out of bounds for Solidity contracts

Tags: testing, solidity, hardhat

does it make sence to test the contract for out of bounds error, and if so, how to do it?
E.G.: I have a function that's supposed to have uint8 parameter. To prevent from its future change to uint256, i'd like to have a test.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always make sense to test out-of-bounds errors unless you have a specific case.

In my case, I am calling an external contract that should return a value from an array at a specific index. I expect the function to revert, but it doesn't, so I'm adding a test.

Since you're using hardhat, I recommend using the `revertedWithPanic` method from the `hardhat-chai-matchers` library. Here's the link to their docs on reverts: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview#reverts